# get custom attributes from an Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item object

Tags: magento

I’m writing an Observer for manage the order’s items, I need to send an email for every order based on some custom attributes.

The item object is Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item and searching around I’ve tried methods like getData(’my_code’), getCustomAttribute, getAttributeText without success.

I need to get the category, size, color and some custom attributes…
Here my little code

```
class Example_OrderMod_Model_Observer{

  public function doSomething($observer){
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

    $id_ordine = $order->getRealOrderId();
    $cliente = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getCustomerName();

    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    //$item is an instance of Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item

      $quantita =  $item->getQtyOrdered();
      $codice_giglio =  $item->getSku();

      //echo $item->getData('size');
      var_dump($item->getAttributeText('size'));
      var_dump($item->getProductOptionByCode('size'));
      var_dump($item->getProductOptionByCode('famiglia'));

    }
//    die();
  }
}
```

any ideas?

many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll probably want to load up the product object, and then get your data off of that object. That will allow you to utilize all the methods you are looking for:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
$size = $product->getAttributeText('size');
```

Comment: Use getProductId() instead of getId()... there is a different between the item's ID and the product it represents.

Answer (score 4):

If $item is instance of Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item you could simply use:

```
$product = $item->getProduct();
```

Answer (score 3):

**solution of display custom attributes**

```
function getAttr($product_id, $attributeName) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
    $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
    $attributeValue = null;
    if(array_key_exists($attributeName , $attributes)) {
        $attributesobj = $attributes["{$attributeName}"];
        $attributeValue = $attributesobj->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
    }
    return $attributeValue;
}
```

Comment: This is the only working solution to the question as I understand it, and the problem as I faced it.

Comment: `$object{$someprop}` === `$object["{$someprop}"]`

Answer (score 2):

When i tried the above methods it didn't worked somehow in my observer class. Actually the product model is unable to load with the above code block. I found this code and it worked. It loads the product model in observer.

`$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');`

`$productId = $product->getIdBySku($item->getSku());`

`$product->load($productId);`